# How do I use string-literal type annotations for multiple possible argument types?

Tags: python, type-annotation

We can use objects as type annotations:

```
def foo(a: int) -> str:
    return str(a)
```

We can also use string literals as type annotations:

```
def foo(a: "int") -> "str":
    return str(a)
```

But, how do we use string literals for more complex cases such as when we accept multiple argument types? If I used objects I would do:

```
from typing import Union

def foo(a: Union[int, str]) -> str:
    return str(a)
```

What's the equivalent of that if we used string literals? Is there a syntax that allows me to use string literals in such complex cases?

Comment: Incidentally, do you mean `List[Union[int, str]]` in the last case?

Comment: @gmds I think so, so I updated it.

Answer (score 3):

You still just stick quotes around it:

```
from typing import Union

def foo(a: "Union[int, str]") -> "str":
    return str(a)
```

Comment: @multigoodverse: You still need the imports for the tools you're using to understand what `Union` is (and if you're not using any tools that need to understand what the annotations mean, then there's little point to using annotations).